# How to insure that all redux states are loaded before react component rendered?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using the fk_branch_id of the user into redux store when the user login.

And i am initializing jquery datatable in react componentDidMount.
and in datatable initializing i send the fk_branch_id with ajax headers

```
beforeSend: (request) => {
  let branchId = _.isEmpty(this.props.active_branch)?null:this.props.active_branch.branch_id;
  request.setRequestHeader("fk_branch_id", branchId);
},
```

but when the ajax is sent, the fk_branch_id is null because the fk_branch_id from redux state is not loaded yet, so is there any way to insure that the states are fully loaded before componentDidMount are called

Comment: Please provide more code samples. How are you mounting your reducers ? What is the component hierarchy ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this in `componentWillReceiveProps` or the new `getDerivedStateFromProps` if the value isn't available yet right after mounting. Detect that `fk_branch_id` just changed from falsy to truthy:

```
if (!this.props.fk_branch_id && nextProps.fk_branch_id) {
    // send request with nextProps.fk_branch_id
}
```